# How to add validation rules to Antd Form.List

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I have a form which contains a `Form.List`. It will be used to add songs to an album.

I want to make sure that an album contains at least one song, but Form.List only has the props `name` and `children`.

How can I validate this?

Thanks

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: share what you have done so far ?

Comment: There is really not much code to share, but I can add some code snippet later.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Form.List 
name="names"
>
  {fields => (
    <div>
      {fields.map(field => (
        <Form.Item {...field}>
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
</Form.List>
```

This is the [solution from antd docs](https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#Form.List). From my experience I can add this handy methods and errors inside a **Form.List** children render method besides.

```
 <Form.List
        name="names"
      >
        {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've spent several hours without realizing that there's a `<Form.ErrorList errors={errors} />` in the component

Answer (score 0):

make a condition to see if the album contains at least one song.
If not, Do not render the form.list
If yes, render the form.list

Comment: That is not what I want to do. This is a form to create an album inside which I am able to add songs through the Form.List. I want to be able to add validation rules to the Form.List so that the user inserts at least one song.

Comment: You can assign to a string variable when user select it. And for each selection, verify if the song equals to the variable where a song is stored